# What are alternate usage of websockets (except comet)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, comet, websocket

I know websockets provide a better solution for comet (reverse Ajax, often done with long-polling).

Can we use them for something else?

Example:

- Can we use them to communicate between browsers?

- Can we use them to communicate with a Java application (instead of using an applet)? Or to another application (rather than using Flash)?

- Can we use them to communicate with another server than the one that served the main page (cross-domain)?

- Other types of usage?

Comment: Can somebody elaborate on the down-votes?

Answer (score 0):

- Can we use them to communicate between browsers?

The server can fetch data and flush it to someone else, so that you can send data from one client to another. So yes it's possible, but not directly.

- Can we use them to communicate with a Java application (instead of using an applet)? Or to another application (rather than using Flash)?

I'm not completely sure what you mean with "Java application", but the server can basically do everything at its side.

- Can we use them to communicate with another server than the one that served the main page (cross-domain)?

Sure, that's one of the interesting parts of WebSockets.

- Other types of usage?

There are tons of opportunities created by WebSockets, one of which being the fact that you can create a multiplayer game, which is certainly interesting.

Comment: With "Java application", I meant standalone Java application, running in parallel with the browser. You can have a communication between both through a java applet.